# OpenCart 2.0.1.1 search description

Tags: php

Default Opencart 2.0.1.1 search is in product names. How can I make the default search in product names and descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I just need search results always include 'search in description' so I change below code in file catalog/controller/product/search.php

```
        $filter_data = array(
            'filter_name'         => $search,
            'filter_tag'          => $tag,
            'filter_description'  => $description,
            'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
            'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
            'sort'                => $sort,
            'order'               => $order,
            'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
            'limit'               => $limit
        );
```

to

```
        $filter_data = array(
            'filter_name'         => $search,
            'filter_tag'          => $tag,
            'filter_description'  => 'true',
            'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
            'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
            'sort'                => $sort,
            'order'               => $order,
            'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
            'limit'               => $limit
        );
```

But if you want to make just default other than always then you may need more effort on this file. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are [ways](http://craigmurray.me.uk/opencart-mods/better-search-in-opencart-search-product-description-by-default/) to search in the description, but I would advise you for performances issues to use tags. They're recognized by the default search engine.

For example, if you sell monitors, you would use `IPS`, `LED`, `LCD`, or `widescreen` tags.

Comment: I am still interested how to make default insite search for eshop products to go not only through names but through descriptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

To include the descripcion in you search, you will have to request the description in the search.

This is the file that you have to edit:

catalog/controller/product/search.php

Include this code in the search:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
    $description = $this->request->get['description'];
} else {
    $description = '';
}
```

Like this:

```
<?php 
class ControllerProductSearch extends Controller {  
    public function index() { 
        $this->language->load('product/search');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image'); 

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $search = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $search = '';
        } 

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['tag'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $tag = '';
        } 

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $description = $this->request->get['description'];
        } else {
            $description = '';
        }
```

Regards,

Comment: This is included by default. I have to first press search and then after no results select "include search in description" and search again. I want to search in description by default.